# Is it a bad idea to have 6000 directories with 6000 files in each one?

Tags: performance, large-files

This is a strange question, I know.  But I am working on some code and dealing with a lot of flat files that I am generating.  I can't use any kind of database (for various reasons which are not relevant).  But currently I am generating about 4GB of data and it is very slow to read or perform certain search operations on those files.

I have been looking at the structures and figured out the most efficient way for me to perform my search operations is if I effectively had a file structure where there would be approx 6000 directories and each one would roughly have 6000 files in it.  Yes, that means in total I would have 36,000,000 files that are all very lightweight (lets say 100 KB?).

The reason I think structuring them like this is going to be more efficient is that my code can locate and open files relatively quickly, however if the file is large it takes a long time for it to read and load into RAM which makes things super slow.

So my question really is, to me it sounds like a good idea to do this 36 million file structure, but it's a lot of pain for me to refactor the code to set this up and I don't want to do it to realise new problems, so wanted to know whether anyone has experience of this and whether it's a bad idea or not?

Edit Additional Info:
These files will effectively live on a Ubuntu OS where the filesystem is mounted onto a docker container.  I also have a requirement (less important) to zip these files up and send them to another server (potentially yucky windows).

Comment: 36,000,000 files * 100 KB = 3.6 TB, not 4 GB.  But 6000 entries is not bad, especially for a filesystem that does directory indexing or hashing.  You'll want to make sure it actually has capacity for that number of files (e.g., with some Linux filesystems, the number of inodes is fixed when you created the filesystem).  If you would say more about the OS and filesystem setup, you could get more detailed answers.

Comment: Sorry, it's late and I've been coding for 15 hours straight, so cba to check the math.  The point is the file count is roughly correct and the files will be light weight, we are not talking about large files and large quantities of them, but we are talking about very small files with large quantities of them.

Comment: @NateEldredge added more info as requested.  Interesting you mention there are file limits, didn't know that was a thing.  Any rough ideas of what they generally are?

Comment: For comparison, my Firefox cache directory contains 30000 files, no problems there.

Comment: It's whatever was selected when the fs was created and could be nearly anything.  Do `df -i` to see what the limits are on your filesystem.  Some filesystems, e.g. btrfs, don't have such limits and metadata can use arbitrary amounts of disk, in which case you may see 0s.

Comment: $ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      2580480 238376 2342104   10% /

Comment: Hm what am I looking for in that output exactly? That's the root mount from the df -i output.  That's a nice comparison to make with firefox, didn't think of that!

Comment: Your filesystem has a total of 2.5 million inodes, of which 238,000 are in use and the remaining 2.3 million are free.  That's a lot less than 36 million so you'll have to use a different filesystem on another partition, or recreate this one with more inodes (back up everything, do `mkfs.ext4` or whatever with a larger `-N` argument, and restore).

Comment: This part is really more system administration than programming and so should be taken to Unix.SE or AskUbuntu instead.

Comment: "Sorry, it's late and I've been coding for 15 hours straight," - there's your problem!

Comment: @NateEldredge wow, nice spot! Thanks that's exactly the sort of thing I was looking for, I knew there would be problems but wasn't sure exactly what they would be.  Now that I think about it, part of the problem is the files are JSON data and have to be read in their entierty to be parsed, perhaps if I use something else like CSV, I can read them in buffer streams and make things very quick too.

Comment: @MitchWheat LOL, I agree I need some sleep.  I'll think about this tomorrow lol.

Comment: @NateEldredge regarding platform comment, well the application is designed to run on any platform in theory, currently it's Linux, next year it may be Windows.  Didn't want to limit the question to a specific platform.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you `can't use any kind of database`, but can you make one? Do your files have a limit on length? Let's say 100K is a maximum size. Then you can have 6,000 files where each of them contains 6,000 JSON data pieces started on 100K marks.

That sounds a bit limiting. Alternatively, you can build an index in each file: 6,000 int offsets to each JSON.

These methods provide random access to your "files".

If you need to modify those JSONs, the first method is easier.